# Cleaner way of dealing with these if clauses?

Tags: java, if-statement

I am wondering what would be a cleaner way of dealing with this bunch of `if` clauses. As an aditional information, it's an exception handler to be used in a Spark Framework study project.

This piece of code does its job and it's readable, but a possible further extension would convert it into a monster. Do you have any suggestion to refactor it?

```
    public ExceptionHandler<? super java.lang.Exception> handler() {
        return (e, request, response) -> {
            ErrorMessage error;

            if (e instanceof SomeException1) {
                response.status(422);
                error = new ErrorMessage("message1", e.getMessage());
            } else if (e instanceof SomeException2) {
                response.status(404);
                error = new ErrorMessage("message2", e.getMessage());
            } else if (e instanceof SomeException3) {
                response.status(500);
                error = new ErrorMessage("message3", e.getMessage());
            } else {
                response.status(500);
                error = new ErrorMessage("message4", e.getMessage());
            }

            [...]
        };
    }
```

Edit for clarification:

This piece of code is part of an exception handler method which is registered in the application's main class using Spark's `exception()` method. Something like this:

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      //register the exception handler
      exception(Exception.class, errorsHandler.handler()); //handler() is the method showed above.
    }    
}
```

Comment: Where is the `error` used in the further program flow?

Comment: How about just a helper method like `error = setError(response, 500, "message4");` to reduce the code duplication?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good way to avoid long if-/else chains is to use a mapping table. You could use a Map, that maps the Exception class to the status code. Like this:

```
private static Map<Class<?>, Integer> errorCodeMapping = new HashMap<>();

{
    errorCodeMapping.put(SomeException.class, 422);
    ...
}
```

Your exception handler would then set the code like

```
response.status(errorCodeMapping.get((e.getClass()));
```

The same can be done for a exception class to error message mapping.
This way you could also provide a setter for new mappings, that have not to be hard coded into the Handler class itself.

Comment: Using `getClass()` as-is is not a good idea, because `instanceof` also returns true if the object is of a *subclass* of that Exception.

Comment: ... but you could just iterate the entries in the Map (maybe use an ordered  `LinkedMap`) and do the original `instanceof` checks in a loop. Still, you will need a second map for the message.

Comment: I think this answer is a fine start `Map<Class<? extends Exception>, Pair<Integer, String>>` for response status and message. If `get` returns null, try the exception's super class. In fact the data could be put in an XML of properties file, to decouple all.

Answer (score 1):

My version would be something like this:

```
class ExceptionInfo {
   Class<? extends Exception> cls;
   int errCode;
   String message;

   public ExceptionInfo(Class<? extends Exception> cls, int errCode, String message) {
       this.cls = cls;
       this.errCode = errCode;
       this.message = message;
   }
}

// Note that the last item is Exception.class, to serve as a default.

final static List<ExceptionInfo> EXCEPTION_LIST = Arrays.asList(
    new ExceptionInfo( SomeException1.class, 422, "message1"),
    new ExceptionInfo( SomeException2.class, 404, "message2"),
    new ExceptionInfo( SomeException3.class, 500, "message3"),
    new ExceptionInfo( Exception.class, 500, "message4" )
);

ExceptionInfo searchException( Exception e ) {
    return EXCEPTION_LIST.stream()
        .filter( info -> info.cls.isInstance(e) )
        .findFirst()
        .orElseThrow( IllegalStateException::new );
}
```

With this, you can get the `ExceptionInfo` compatible with the given `e`, and then use its `errCode` and `message`. This is fully compatible with `instanceOf`. Of course, you can use getters instead of accessing the fields of this mini-class directly.